# Java generic methods difference between two arrays

Tags: java, generic-method

I am trying to write a method that will find the difference between elements of two arrays of the same length and here is what I did until now:

```
  public static <T extends Object> T method(T[] array,T[] array1){
      T[]difference;
      difference = new T[array.length]; //error :generic array creation
      for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          difference[i]=array[i]-array1[i]; //error:bad operand types for binary operator

      }
      return (T)difference;
  }
```

but it constantly returns to me a message that i wrote next to the line of the code that it refers to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Java doesn't support generic array creation. You can get round this by creating an array of `Object`s and then casting.
2. The bigger problem is that java doesn't support operator overloading, and subtraction (i.e. `-`) is only supported by primitive types. This is compouded by the fact that generics *doesn't* support primitive types, which makes what you're trying to do impossible on its own.

To get round these problems, you'd need to do a number of things:

1. Don't use primitives, but you can used boxed types instead (so instead of `int` you'd use `Integer`, etc.).
2. You need to tell your function how to find the difference between two objects of the required type. You can achieve this by defining a 'Subtractor' interface.

I'd also suggest using lists instead of arrays, as these handle generics much more nicely. You can easily convert between lists and arrays afterwards if needed.

So, as a skeleton of a solution, here's what I'd propose:

1. Define a generic interface for finding differences:

   ```
   interface Subtractor<T> {
       T subtract(T a, T b);
   }
   ```
2. Rewrite your method to use lists, and to take a subtractor as an argument:

   ```
   public static <T> List<T> difference(
           List<? extends T> listA, List<? extends T> listB, Subtractor<T> subtractor) {
       int resultSize = Math.min(listA.size(), listB.size());
       List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(resultSize);
       for(int i=0; i<resultSize; ++i) {
           result.add(subtractor.subtract(listA.get(i), listB.get(i)));
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. Define subtractor implementations for the types you want to be able to use the method with:

   ```
   class IntSubtractor implements Subtractor<Integer> {
       @Override
       Integer subtract(Integer a, Integer b) {
           return Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() - b.intValue());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use your method. You can use `Arrays.asList` for turning arrays into lists, but you can't use arrays of primitives unfortunately.

   ```
   Integer[] a = new Integer[]{5,6,7,8};
   Integer[] b = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};
   Integer[] c = difference(Arrays.asList(a), Arrays.asList(b), new IntSubtractor())
           .toArray(new Integer[4]);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your array values are numbers. It is difficult to provide a general solution. But I would say this might work for your case:

```
public static <T extends Number> Number[] method(T[] array, T[] array1){
      Number[]difference = new Number[array.length];
      for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++){
          difference[i]= Double.valueOf(array[i].doubleValue() - array1[i].doubleValue());
      }
      return difference;
 }
```